# Getting an error of substring not found for below code

Tags: python, string

```
s2 = "fast and furious series from one to seven"
print "s2.index('e', 50, 0) : ", s2.index('e', 50, 0)
```

Error :

```
print "s2.index('e', 50, 0) : ", s2.index('e', 50, 0)
ValueError: substring not found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking Python to find `e` in an empty slice; the second and third argument are the *start* and *end* indices. `s2[50:0]` is an empty string:

```
>>> s2 = "fast and furious series from one to seven"
>>> s2[50:0]
''
```

If you wanted to find text by searching from the end, use the [`str.rindex()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rindex):

```
>>> s2.rindex('e')
39
```

Comment: But according to the code it will search in reverse order from right to left, I tried the above code by changing start indices like , s2.index('e', 40, 0).

Still I am getting same error

Comment: If i am writting similar code for find() method, then it is working but not for index () method. Please explain this

Comment: @NikhilKadam: what makes you think it'll search in reverse? According to what code?

Comment: What I have learnt through tutorials, find() method and index() method both determine if str occurs in string or in a substring of string. Hence code executed for find() method is showing results but not index() method.                                                                                                                                           
print "s2.find('e', 10, 0) : ",s2.find('e', 10, 0)

Comment: @NikhilKadam: `find` and `index` find the exact same things, with `index` raising an exception if nothing is found and `find` returning `-1`. There are no other differences. The `end` argument being smaller or equal to `start` means you search through an empty string and will never find anything.

Comment: ok.. thats the difference.. thank you.. as I m learning python, this will help me alot.